# Promises in a mobx store

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, es6-promise, mobx

I am not sure how to implement promises in my mobx store. I have two actions that I would like to run sequentially in a loop and make sure to wait for the first to finish before running the second. Here is an example of my store code. Please ask for any further clarification and I'll be sure to add it. I tried to simplify the code to just what I thought was necessary to find a solution. Thanks!

```
import { observable, action } from 'mobx';

import Store from '../support/store';

class Upload extends Store {
  @observable fileList = null;  // array of files to be uploaded
  @observable processedFile = null;  // single file pre-processed for upload

  @action processFile(file) {
    // takes file from fileList array, 'processes' it and 
    // places the result in this.processedFile
  }

  @action post() {
    // makes a POST request, uploading this.processedFile
    // sets this.processedFile = null
  }

  @action postFileList() {
    // loops over the array this.fileList
    // runs this.processFile(file)
    // waits until processFile(file) is finished
    // runs post()
    // waits until post() is finished
    // removes file from the this.fileList array
  }
}
```

Comment: is `processFile` asynchronous or just `post`?

Comment: @Tholle `processFile` is also asynchronous.

Comment: make the postFileList function `async` and write the code exactly like you wrote before. The beauty of mobx is that you don't need any special specific code for it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are doing something asynchronous inside the action, you need to make sure to [**wrap the asynchronously called function in an action as well**](https://mobxjs.github.io/mobx/refguide/action.html).

You could make a recursive `postFileList` that exits when there are no more files left in `fileList`.

**Example**

```
class Upload extends Store {
  @observable fileList = [];
  @observable processedFile = null;

  @action processFile(file) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      const file = this.fileList[0];
      setTimeout(action(() => {
        this.processedFile = file.processed;
        resolve();
      }), 1000); 
    });
  }

  @action post() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      const file = this.processedFile;
      setTimeout(action(() => {
        this.processedFile = null;
        resolve();
      }), 1000); 
    });
  }

  @action postFileList() {
    if (this.fileList.length === 0) {
      return;
    }
    this.processFile()
      .then(() => this.post())
      .then(action(() => {
        this.fileList.shift();
        this.postFileList();
      }));
  }
}
```